# Android ExpandableListview with Room database

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I need to populate an `ExpandableListView` whose data is fetched from `Room` database.

There are answers on how to do this with `SQLiteDatabase`:

1) [Android ExpandableListView and SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644914/android-expandablelistview-and-sqlite-database)

2) [Android ExpandableListView From Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758645/android-expandablelistview-from-database)

Is it possible to achieve the same with Room Database?

I have two tables: a) GroupHeader b) GroupContent

```
@Entity
public class GroupHeader implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int groupId;
    private String groupName;
    private String otherProperty1;
    private String otherProperty2;
    /* getters and setters */
}

@Entity
public class GroupContent implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int contentId;
    private int groupId;
    private String contentName;
    private String otherProperty3;
    private String otherProperty4;    
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using `@Relation`.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation

```
@Entity
public class GroupHeader implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int groupId;
    private String groupName;
    private String otherProperty1;
    private String otherProperty2;
    /* getters and setters */
}

@Entity
public class GroupContent implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int contentId;
    private int groupId;
    private String contentName;
    private String otherProperty3;
    private String otherProperty4;    
    /* getters and setters */
}

public class Wrapper {
    @Embedded
    private GroupHeader header;
    @Relation(parentColumn="groupId", entityColumn="groupId", entity=GroupContent.class)
    private List<GroupContent> contents;
    /*getters & setters*/
}
```